# Java8: how to copy values of selected fields from one object to other using lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to understand new functions of java8: forEach and lambda expressions.

Trying to rewrite this function:

```
public <T extends Object> T copyValues(Class<T> type, T source, T result)
        throws IllegalAccessException
{
    for(Field field : getListOfFields(type)){
        field.set(result, field.get(source));
    }
    return result;
}
```

using lambda.

I think it should be something like this but can't make it right:

```
() -> {
     return getListOfFields(type).forEach((Field field) -> {
            field.set(result, field.get(source));
     });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use functions in the following way:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface CopyFunction<T> {
    T apply(T source, T result) throws Exception;
}

public static <T> CopyFunction<T> createCopyFunction(Class<T> type) {
    return (source, result) -> {
        for (Field field : getListOfFields(type)) {
            field.set(result, field.get(source));
        }
        return result;
    };
}
```

And then:

```
A a1 = new A(1, "one");
A a2 = new A(2, "two");
A result = createCopyFunction(A.class).apply(a1, a2);
```

The `CopyFunction` functional interface is pretty much the same as [BinaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) except that `BinaryOperator` doesn't throw an exception. If you want to handle exceptions within a function, you can use the `BinaryOperator` instead.

Comment: Yeah this is Java8 way to do it 

Comment: @MahendraKapadne you mean, unnecessarily wrapping code with a function instead of simply calling a method, making both, caller and implementation, more complicated, is the Java 8 way?

Comment: @Holger OP didn't ask "should I wrap this code with a function?", he asked "is it possible to do this?": _surely it is not for production, just to understand what is possible. So there is no way to replace copyValues function with lambda?_

Comment: @KirillSimonov your answer is addressing the OP’s question (well, you’re not using `forEach`), nothing wrong with that, but I didn’t agree with Mahendra Kapadne’s comment saying “this is Java8 way to do it”.

Comment: @Holger I agree that in this particular case there is no benefit from using lambdas and `forEach`

Answer (score 5):

The loop can be replaced by

```
getListOfFields(type).forEach((field) -> field.set(result, field.get(source)));
```

However, that `forEach` method call has no return value, so you still need to

```
return result;
```

separately.

The full method:

```
public <T extends Object> T copyValues(Class<T> type, T source, T result)
        throws IllegalAccessException
{
    getListOfFields(type).forEach((field) -> field.set(result, field.get(source)));
    return result;
}
```

EDIT, I didn't notice the issue with the exception. You'll have to catch the exception and throw some unchecked exception. For example:

```
public <T extends Object> T copyValues(Class<T> type, T source, T result)
{
    getListOfFields(type).forEach (
      (field) -> {
        try {
            field.set(result, field.get(source));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException (ex);
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work as it stands because the calll to `field.set()` might throw `IllegalAccessException` (a checked exception).

Comment: Thanks! But can I replace whole generic function somehow? Thought that generics are good candidates to be replaced by lambda expressions? Is use of forEach method a blocker here or am I expecting too much?

Comment: Yes, Elevate is right, it is not compiling. I still do not get something here. Can I add throws declaration to lambda expression?

Comment: After adding try/catch it is working as expected:

        getListOfFields(typ).forEach(
                    (field) -> {try { field.set(result, field.get(source));} catch (IllegalAccessException ex){}});
        return result;

Comment: Yes, but you probably don't want to swallow exceptions like that. Your code is now longer and logically worse than it was before!

Comment: @Robert yes, I didn't notice the issue with the exception handling. See edit. It's probably better not to use a lambda expression in this case.

Comment: Thanks Elevate, surely it is not for production, just to understand what is possible. So there is no way to replace `copyValues` function with lambda?

Comment: @Robert there is, this answer showed it; but *plz* don't refactor any production code in this manner